# Is Jiren stronger than a God of Destruction?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

There have been several references to a mortal that might be stronger than a God of Destruction, both in the anime and manga. Is this person supposed to be Jiren and if so, is he indeed stronger than a God of Destruction, or is it still unknown exactly how strong he is?

Comment: Will come back to this once I get home and can timestamp the anime, but there is at least one instance where another God of Destruction talks about how Jiren's Universe must be the Universe of the Mortal stronger than a God of Destruction; and (I believe during the 2 part Jiren vs Goku fight) Belmod himself makes mention to Jiren being stronger than he is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question would be a yes and a no.

Firstly, it has to be noted that all gods of destruction are equally strong. In the anime, it was stated by Vados that Beerus is stronger than Champa and right before the tournament, Whis stated Vermouth might be stronger than Beerus although Beerus said that he only lost a wrestling match.

Even in the manga, when we see the exhibition match square off, we see Beerus being able to fight off multiple gods of destruction at the same time and he along with Quitella were the last 2 standing(It has to also be noted here that in the manga, Quitella is the fighter who defeated Beerus in the arm wrestling match). Vermouth also didn't seem that injured at the end of the fight.

According to the official description release on Jiren, it states that he is at the level of a god of destruction. In the anime, while Jiren was effortlessly pushing off the spirit bomb, it was stated by Whis that Jiren is as strong as a God of destruction or possibly even stronger than his.  So by this, we can conclude that Jiren is >= Vermouth, definitely not way stronger but it is indeed possible he is stronger.

At the same time, there do exist multiple gods of destruction and Jiren might not be stronger than the strongest god of destruction across the multiverse.

So I think the best way to represent Jiren's power is to state that it is at the level of a god of destruction. Just like we see Champa hold his own against Beerus despite Beerus being stronger, Jiren would easily be able to hold his own even against the stronger God of destruction across the multiverse.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in ep. 109 and 110, his power just terrified even Beerus the God of Destruction and Goku after that Ultra Instinct form was not able to defeat him.
Just going toe-to-toe and dodging, but he hardly took hit which was nothing for Jiren.

I would say Jiren will take this fight as he is insanely, monstrously strong. He didn't even increase his power to the final limits.

Think about it. [Jiren's true Power (on YouTube)](https://youtu.be/-QjLk-IjlMQ).